# Cannot find a library when running PySpark job with external jar files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mqtt

I have PySpark job `InitiatorSpark.py` with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Test") \
    .getOrCreate()

lines = (spark
             .readStream
             .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
             .option("topic","my_topic")
             .load("tcp://{}".format("127.0.0.1:1883")))
```

I run it as follows:

```
spark-submit --jars lib/spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11-2.2.1.jar InitiatorSpark.py
```

The Spark starts, but then it fails at line `.load("tcp://{}".format("127.0.0.1:1883")))` with the message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClientPersistence
```

It seems that the class `MqttClientPersistence` cannot be found though I provided a correct JAR file. Inside `lib` I have two files:

```
spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11-2.2.1-sources.jar 
spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11-2.2.1.jar
```

What is wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this code by adding 3 JAR files to the spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --jars lib/spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11-2.2.1.jar,lib/spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11-2.2.1.jar,lib/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar InitiatorSpark.py
```